# For loop on Google apps running slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with Links to drive folders and I'm trying to see which ones are empty or not.
I know the spreadsheet urls start at C3 and was trying to future proof it by just searching until the last row but the runtime is slowing down the more rows i have.

Here is my current script:

```
function checkFileExists(){
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getDataRange();
  var values = range.getRichTextValues();
  for (var row = 2; row<values.length; row++) {
    if (!values[row].join("")) break;
    for(var col = 2; col<values[row].length; col++) {
      if (!values[row][col].getLinkUrl()) continue;
      if(!(DriveApp.getFolderById(values[row][col].getLinkUrl().replace(/^.+\//, '')).getFiles()).hasNext()){
        range.getCell(row+1,col+1).setBackground("#e06666");
      }
      else{
        range.getCell(row+1,col+1).setBackground("#93c47d");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this more efficient and reduce the runtime?

Edit: Thanks to Tanaike's answer I'm now using this code, it works great.
Starts from C3 and goes to the last piece of data in the sheet (that is in column C or further)

```
function checkFileExists2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var startRow = 3; // Start row for the range
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 3, lastRow - startRow + 1, lastColumn - 2);
  var values = range.getRichTextValues();
  var { rows, requests } = values.reduce((o, row, i) => {
    row.forEach((cell, j) => {
      var link = cell.getLinkUrl();
      if (link) {
        var folderId = link.split("/").pop();
        var q = `'${folderId}' in parents and trashed=false`;
        var fields = "files(id)";
        o.rows.push(sheet.getRange(i + startRow, j + 3).getA1Notation());
        o.requests.push({
          method: "GET",
          endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&pageSize=1&q=${encodeURIComponent(q)}&fields=${encodeURIComponent(fields)}`,
        });
      }
    });
    return o;
  }, { rows: [], requests: [] });
  var results = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
  var res = results.reduce((o, { files }, i) => {
    o[files.length > 0 ? "#93c47d" : "#e06666"].push(rows[i]);
    return o;
  }, { "#e06666": [], "#93c47d": [] });
  Object.entries(res).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v.length > 0) {
      sheet.getRangeList(v).setBackground(k);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `setBackground` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will be high.
- Also, I thought that the cost of `DriveApp.getFolderById(values[row][col].getLinkUrl().replace(/^.+\//, '')).getFiles()).hasNext()` might be able to be reduced.

In this case, I thought that following 2 patterns.

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the Drive service (DriveApp) is used for checking the existence of files in the folders.

```js
function checkFileExists1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("C3:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getRichTextValues();
  var colors = values.map(([c]) => {
    var link = c.getLinkUrl();
    if (link) {
      var folderId = link.split("/").pop();
      var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles();
      return [files.hasNext() ? "#93c47d": "#e06666"];
    }
    return [null]
  });
  range.setBackgrounds(colors);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Drive API is used for checking the existence of files in the folders. In this case, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, this sample uses the batch request. When the batch request is used, the process cost can be reduced. [Ref Author: me](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script)

But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the batch request cannot be directly used with the Google Apps Script. So, I have created a Google Apps Script library. Please install it before you run the script. [Ref Author: me](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install)

```js
function checkFileExists2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange("C3:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getRichTextValues();
  var { rows, requests } = values.reduce((o, [c], i) => {
    var link = c.getLinkUrl();
    if (link) {
      var folderId = link.split("/").pop();
      var q = `'${folderId}' in parents and trashed=false`
      var fields = "files(id)";
      o.rows.push(`C${i + 3}`);
      o.requests.push({
        method: "GET",
        endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=allDrives&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&pageSize=1&q=${encodeURIComponent(q)}&fields=${encodeURIComponent(fields)}`,
      });
    }
    return o;
  }, { rows: [], requests: [] });
  var results = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/drive/v3", requests });
  var res = results.reduce((o, { files }, i) => {
    o[files.length > 0 ? "#93c47d": "#e06666"].push(rows[i]);
    return o;
  }, { "#e06666": [], "#93c47d": [] });
  Object.entries(res).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v.length > 0) {
      sheet.getRangeList(v).setBackground(k);
    }
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [setBackgrounds(color) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)
- [BatchRequest](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- [setBackground(color) of Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setbackgroundcolor)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: This works for the column C but I want a solution that checks from C3 to the EOF of possible.

Comment: @Roy503 Thank you for replying. From `This works for the column C`, I could understand that your issue was resolved. About `but I want a solution that checks from C3 to the EOF of possible.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand it. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new issue? I would like to think of a new solution by correctly understanding your new issue. I apologize for my poor English skill again. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have modified your code snippet a bit to now make it work for C3 to the last piece of data in the sheet.

Comment: @Roy503 Thank you for replying. From your reply, I could understand it. And, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.